# GUI tool for analyzing assembly, produced by Java JIT

Tags: software-development, java, assembly

I know there is a tool, which consumes Java VM output with `-XX:+PrintAssembly` and have 3-columns GUI:

- Left column with Java code,
- The middle one with bytecode and
- The right one with assembly.

Please, remind me the name of this tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is [JITWatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch).

[image]
<sup>Screenshot of GUI</sup>